# Google cloud SSH download file not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I've been using the "Download File" button on top of the SSH console window for google cloud (I'm using a linux/debian server) to download files, but suddenly one day, it stopped working.

It acts like it's working (I get the "Transferred 1 Item" popup at the bottom with a green check mark) but the file isn't there in my "downloads" folder in windows. I tried just downloading random files from chrome and they end up in my "downloads" folder. It's just that the SSH downloads are not showing up in the "downloads" folder.

Uploading files through the "Upload File" button on the SSH works.
I tried a large file download, and it takes several minutes (as if it's actually downloading) but I couldn't find it in my local machine.

I've even done a file name search in my whole local drive, but still couldn't find it.

Again, it used to work, but suddenly stopped working.

Does anyone have any advice on this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered this problem yesterday, but it went back to normal after cleaning cache. Maybe you can try it.